# Cannot connect theme for Angular Material

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

I using Angular Material component and try to use a prebuilt theme

I added this row to my component css `@import '@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css';`

But  still get an error

> Could not find Angular Material core theme. Most Material components may not work as expected. For more info refer to the theming guide: https://material.angular.io/guide/theming

Here is app.module.ts code

```
 import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import {CustomMaterialModule} from "./CustomMaterialModule";
import { PaymentsComponent } from './payments/payments.component';
import { MatPaginatorModule, MatCheckboxModule} from '@angular/material';
import {FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    PaymentsComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    CustomMaterialModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    MatPaginatorModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,

  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Where can be my trouble?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like I found answer

I need to add

```
    providers: [
    {
      provide: MATERIAL_SANITY_CHECKS,
      useValue: false
    }
  ],
```

Into app.module.ts and now I don't have this error